# Can I use a wired "Xbox360 gamepad for Windows" on an Xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, controllers

I currently own a "Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller for Windows". This is obviously the exact same gamepad in its shape as the ones which come with the Xbox console.

My question is: can I use it on an Xbox console as well, or can it be connected only to PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It works. Just plug it in and it will be recognized instantly. If you want to attach more of them you can also use an USB hub.

Answer (score 3):

PC Xbox controllers and normal Xbox controllers are exactly the same, so you will have no problem using them interchangeably.